# Does RTCPeerConnection work in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: javascript, win-universal-app, webrtc, voip, microsoft-edge

I am currently working on VoIP using WebRTC. It's going to be a UWP application written in JavaScript.

Now, I am trying to check whether it works or not by testing samples from https://webrtc.github.io/samples on Microsoft Edge.

It turns out that it works fine **except** `RTCPeerConnection`.

For example, when I opened https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/audio in Edge, it gave me `getUserMedia() error: NotFoundError` when I clicked the call button. On Chrome, it works fine.

Another example is when I tried https://apprtc.appspot.com, it gave me

```
Messages:  
Error getting user media: null
getUserMedia error: Failed to get access to local media. Error name was NotFoundError. Continuing without sending a stream.
Create PeerConnection exception: InvalidAccessError

Version:    
gitHash:    c135495bc71e5da61344f098a8209a255f64985f
branch:     master
time:       Fri Apr 8 13:33:05 2016 +0200
```

So, how should I fix that? `Adapter.js` is also called. I also allow everything it needs.

Or I shouldn't use WebRTC for this project. If so, what should I use?

Cheers!

Comment: that looks like an issue with your cam/mic. Check the output of navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices e.g. using [this demo](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Microsoft Edge implements ORTC, a more low-level decentralized cousin of WebRTC that does not have an overarching `RTCPeerConnection` object.

But the good news is that [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter), the official WebRTC polyfill, shims `RTCPeerConnection` for you on Edge, so you should be able to use WebRTC the same way on all the browsers.

For instance, this demo works for me in Edge, Firefox and Chrome.

```js
var pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(), pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection();

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
  .then(stream => pc1.addStream(video1.srcObject = stream))
  .catch(log);

var add = (pc, can) => can && pc.addIceCandidate(can).catch(log);
pc1.onicecandidate = e => add(pc2, e.candidate);
pc2.onicecandidate = e => add(pc1, e.candidate);

pc2.onaddstream = e => video2.srcObject = e.stream;
pc1.oniceconnectionstatechange = e => log(pc1.iceConnectionState);
pc1.onnegotiationneeded = e =>
  pc1.createOffer().then(d => pc1.setLocalDescription(d))
  .then(() => pc2.setRemoteDescription(pc1.localDescription))
  .then(() => pc2.createAnswer()).then(d => pc2.setLocalDescription(d))
  .then(() => pc1.setRemoteDescription(pc2.localDescription))
  .catch(log);

var log = msg => div.innerHTML += "<br>" + msg;
```

```html
<video id="video1" width="160" height="120" autoplay muted></video>
<video id="video2" width="160" height="120" autoplay></video><br>
<div id="div"></div>
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your privacy settings first to allow Edge to access your media devices.
https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10-camera-and-privacy